# Why is the callback always null?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, audiorecord, continuous

I would like to get the audio buffer while recording (in AsyncTask) and to visualize it when the view is on, however, I'm not if this is the correct way to do so. In the following implementation, the callback is always null, not sure where went wrong.

Here is the activity fragment:

```
public class MainPageFragment extends Fragment implements Observer {

    private AudioRecordingDbmHandler visualizerHandler;
    private GLAudioVisualizationView visualizerView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_main_page, container, false);

        visualizerView = new GLAudioVisualizationView.Builder(getContext())

        rootView.setBackgroundColor(Util.getDarkerColor(color));
        rootView.addView(visualizerView, 0);

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        audioRecord = new AudioRecord();
        visualizerHandler = new AudioRecordingDbmHandler();
        audioRecord.callback(visualizerHandler);
        audioRecord.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        visualizerView.linkTo(visualizerHandler);

    }

    public static class AudioRecordingDbmHandler extends DbmHandler<byte[]> implements AudioRecord.RecordingCallback {
        @Override
        protected void onDataReceivedImpl(byte[] bytes, int layersCount, float[] dBmArray, float[] ampsArray) {...}

        public void stop() {
            calmDownAndStopRendering();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataReady(byte[] data) {
            onDataReceived(data);
        }
    }

}
```

and here is the recording:

```
public class AudioRecord extends AsyncTask <Void, double[], Void> {

    public interface RecordingCallback {
        void onDataReady(byte[] data);
    }

    private RecordingCallback recordingCallback = null;

    public AudioRecord callback(RecordingCallback recordingCallback) {
        this.recordingCallback = recordingCallback;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO);
        ...
        byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        ...
        record.startRecording();

        while (true) {

            bytesRead = record.read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

            try {
                if (recordingCallback != null) {
                    recordingCallback.onDataReady(byteBuffer);       
                }
            } finally {
                recordingBufferLock.unlock();
            }
        }
        record.stop();
        record.release();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also tried using onProgressUpdate which resulting in the same issue. It would be great to have some help here.

Comment: Picture is incomplete. Is DbmHandler implementing AudioRecord.RecordingCallback?

Comment: yes it is, you can scroll the code to the right, sorry if it was unclear

Comment: This part? `implements DetectionMode.RecordingCallback`.This callback is not the same as AudioRecord.RecordingCallback. Is it compiling?

Comment: sorry that i did some mistakes while posting, it should be `implements AudioRecord.RecordingCallback`. And yes it complies, just the callback is always null

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
public AudioRecord callback(RecordingCallback recordingCallback) {
    this.recordingCallback = recordingCallback;
    return this;
}
```

to this:

```
public void setCallback(RecordingCallback recordingCallback) {
    this.recordingCallback = recordingCallback;
}
```

Im not sure if it will work, but since you use the callback method like a setter, you dont need to return this.

Feel free to downvote if it does not help you :)